# iframe overwrites my custom css when it loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to load iframe, and after it was loaded to inject to it my custom css style. But when I'm loading the page I see my css style appears for a split second and then the iframe finally loaded it overrides my style and it disappears.

I know, I need to wait until the iframe is loaded, and I tried to do so but without any success.

When I'm stopping debugger after execution of the following codeline, I can see the background changes. But then it disappears.

```
.append('<style> body{background:red;}</style>');
```

Look at the code snippet.

```js
 (function(){
            var iFrame = $('iframe');
            var contents = iFrame.contents();
            var styleTag = contents.find('head').append('<style> body{background:red;}</style>'); 
        })();
```

```css
#my-iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 600px;
        }
        
        #middle-container {
            width: 500px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        
        #iframe-container {
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>iFrame Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="middle-container">
        <div id="iframe-container">
            <iframe id="my-iframe"       src="http://www.w3schools.com">
                <p>Sorry! Your browser doesn't support iFrames</p>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you try giving ! important on the css styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, actually. However, the content will never change and stay changed because you are trying to modify the content of an external resource. Cross-site scripting (security) rules in the browser prevent you from being able to achieve this.

The only way for you to edit the contents of an iframe is to replace the entire contents of the iframe.

Example:

```
$('iframe').load(function() {
  $('iframe').replaceWith('<p>Replacing everything!</p>');
});
```

But then it seems rather pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use jQuery to change the color like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/9vzj7qt8/

```
 (function(){
            var iFrame = $('iframe');
            var contents = iFrame.contents();
            var styleTag = contents.find('body').css("background-color","red"); 
        })();
```